# Struts2 TypedAnnotation issue with xwork

Tags: java, struts2, type-conversion, action

I'm having an issue where regardless of how I implement my action class with typed annotations struts wont use my custom converter, unless I assign the java type to the converter class in xwork properties.

My Action :

```
@TypeConversion(converter = "common.utility.HashMapTypeConverter")
public Map<Long, Long> getCategoryLogVal() {
    return categoryLogVal;
}

@TypeConversion(converter = "common.utility.HashMapTypeConverter")
public void setCategoryLogVal(Map<Long, Long> categoryLogVal) {
    this.categoryLogVal = categoryLogVal;
}
```

By using the annotation alone, my custom class is not used during submit, and the action ends up in a converter error.

However if I add the following to xwork properties file:

```
java.util.Map=common.utility.HashMapTypeConverter
java.util.HashMap=common.utility.HashMapTypeConverter
```

converter code:

```
    public class HashMapTypeConverter extends StrutsTypeConverter {

private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HashMapTypeConverter.class);

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@Override
public Object convertFromString(Map context, String[] values,  Class toClass) {

    if (values == null  || values[0].toString().indexOf(",") == -1 ){
        HashMap<Long,Long> convertedMap = new HashMap<Long,Long>();
        return convertedMap;
    }       
    int key = 0;
    HashMap<Long,Long> convertedMap = new HashMap<Long,Long>();
    String[] mapValues = values[0].toString().substring(1, values[0].length() -1).split(",");       
    try {
        while (key < mapValues.length ) {
            String[] valueAndKey = mapValues[key].toString().trim().split("=");
            convertedMap.put(Long.valueOf(valueAndKey[0]), Long.valueOf(valueAndKey[1]));
            key++;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
         if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
             logger.debug("Conversion from String to Object failed in HashMapTypeConverter class" + mapValues );
         }
         throw new TypeConversionException(e);
    }       
    return convertedMap;
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@Override
public String convertToString(Map context, Object o) {
      Map map  = (Map) o;
      return map == null ? null : map.toString();
}
```

}

It works, but for EVERY MAP in my entire project, which I do not want.

Question is, how can I make sure the converter is only applied for the objects in my action class .

Thanks and regards,

Comment: Did you try to put @Conversion annotation on the class?

Comment: No I did not, the class with the objects is an action so I didnt put anything aside from the typedconversion annotations

Comment: too bad, because it's a key problem in your question.

Comment: Removed the class type mapping from xwork properties, and did the annotation, yet no luck

Comment: Post the code for converter.

Comment: done, pls check the edit

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, I surprised if it worked using global properties.

Comment: What about applying conversion to bean using properties file https://struts.apache.org/docs/type-conversion.html#TypeConversion-ApplyingaTypeConvertertoabeanormodel ?